# Análise de Edição de Tag - opção de Plágio está em inglês

Tags: suporte, tradução

Uma das opções de **Análise de Edição de Tag** está em inglês!

Veja na imagem que a opção de **rejeição por Plágio** o texto está em inglês.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É impressionante! Isso tem ocorrido com uma frequencia assustadora ultimamente, os devs commitam algo pra rede e alguns de nossos snipets são alterados pra ingles. Já passou da hora da SE da um jeito nisso ou vamos ficar perdendo tempo retraduzindo tudo cada vez que alguem la sobe uma nova revisao.

Comment: @Articuno até na SE tem "legados", infelizmente é ter paciência :/

Comment: @Articuno Já tinha reparado essa "instabilidade", mas não sabia o motivo!